# react: access value of input component

Tags: reactjs

I have build an input-field component and need to access its value from parent component. I tried something like document.getelementById(id).value, but it'll return null as value.

**Parent component:**

```
import StateBox from './StateBox.js';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class AdressenListe extends Component {
render() {
    let filteredAdressen = this.props.adressen.filter(
        (asingle) => {
            return asingle.Firma.toLowerCase().indexOf(document.getElementById('Firma').value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
    );

    var anzahl = filteredAdressen.length;

    return (
        <div>
            <StateBox id="Firma" />
            <StateBox id="PLZ" />
            <li>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

**Input-field component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class StateBox extends Component {

//constructor input field
constructor() {
    super();
    //equal to object
    this.state = {
        search: ''
    };
}
updateSearch(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({search: event.target.value});
}

render(){
    return(
        <form className="StateBox">
            <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the state in the parent component and pass function to update that in child component

```
class Parent extends Component {
  this.state = {
    value: ''
  }
  changeValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({value});
  }

  render() {
    return <Child inputValue={this.state.value} changeValue={this.state.changeValue} />
  }

}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    <input value={this.props.inputValue} onChange={(e) => this.props.changeValue(e.target.value)} />
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean: changeValue={this.changeValue}

Comment: Yes. I made the changes

Comment: Still...changeValue prop should have the changeValue function

Comment: Yes I have it from Parent to child.

Comment: No, you have same value for both props: inputValue={this.state.value} changeValue={this.state.value}

Comment: Now... changeValue is not on the state, you are also missing return on the second render, I'll post my own answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of a child component, you need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and make the child component controlled, because that's the way you should code in react.

Taking your code as base:

```
class AdressenListe extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Firma: ''
    };
  }

  changeValue (Firma) {
    this.setState({Firma});
  }

  render() {
    let filteredAdressen = this.props.adressen.filter(
      (asingle) => {
        return asingle.Firma.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.Firma.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      }
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <StateBox inputValue={this.state.Firma} changeValue={this.changeValue.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note how I pass down the necessary props and the state is managed by the parent.

```
class StateBox extends Component {
  render () {
    return <input type="text" value={this.props.inputValue} onChange={(e) => this.props.changeValue(e.target.value)} />
  }
}
```